# why can´t it be an undirected graph?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, adjacency-matrix

I´m stuck here with a question I cannot resolve. the question is why can´t this matrix be an undirected graph? [ [0,1,0], [1,1,1], [0,0,0] ] 
I was told by my teacher that it can´t be an undirected graph. I have to explain why but I really don´t know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second node is connected to the third node. The third node is **not** connected to the second node. This is a one-way connection, which can only happen in directed graphs.

Basically, an undirected graph matrix is always a symmetric matrix - and your matrix is not symmetric.

Comment: Great, thank you, but one last thing, how can I know which node is connected to which node?

Comment: By the very definition of the matrix representation of graphs. Node `#i` is connected to node `#j` iff `M[i,j]`>0.